# Unexpected result when converting json UTC to timestamp and then date

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We receive data in json format with timestamp represented in UTC. When convert json to timestamp_tz field  it casts successfully  (SQL is executed in Australia : +11h), however when the same result is converting back to date it refers back to UTC and returns result that is not matching timestamp_tz date. This turns out to be issue when using with view and try to add where clause xxx::date = 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Example:

```
select jj:TransactionDatetime::TIMESTAMP_TZ full_date,
       jj:TransactionDatetime::TIMESTAMP_TZ::date round_date,
       jj:TransactionDatetime::TIMESTAMP_TZ::date = '2020-11-14' is_it_same_date
from 
(
select parse_json('
        {
         
          "TransactionDatetime": "2020-11-13 23:26:31+00"
          
        }'
) jj ) dd
```

Result

```
FULL_DATE,ROUND_DATE,IS_IT_SAME_DATE
"2020-11-14 10:26:31.000","2020-11-13","false"
```

FULL_DATE is 14-Nov-2020 with time potion - that is converted from the original json UTC timestamp

ROUND_DATE is supposed to represent date only portion from FULL_DATE. It does that but using UTC representation and this way removes one day.

As result if I have view on top of that data users start using date in "where" clause and receive unexpected result

I expect that ROUND_DATE should be "2020-11-14"

I think that is unexpected behaviour that needs fixing at snowflake.Certainly there is workaround but should work natively.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
alter session set timezone = 'Australia/Sydney';
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(); -- returns 2020-11-24 23:44:24.013 +1100 as of now
select '2020-11-13 23:26:31+00'::TIMESTAMP_TZ as full_date; -- returns 2020-11-13 23:26:31.000 +0000
select '2020-11-13 23:26:31+00'::TIMESTAMP_TZ::date as date_only; -- return 2020-11-13
select '2020-11-13 23:26:31+00'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ as full_date; -- returns 2020-11-14 10:26:31.000 +1100 
select '2020-11-13 23:26:31+00'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ::date as date_only; --returns 2020-11-14
```

Comment: Thanks Sergiu,
It works fine when using TIMESTAMP_LTZ::date. 
Session was already 'Australia/Sydney';
TIMESTAMP_TZ displays Au timezone considering UTC format but any operations on the value work with original value. So if source data comes in UTC is better to use LTZ.